# change dialog typeface to use external fonts

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I need to change the dialog's typeface to use an external font that supports some unicode characters. Unfortunately, there is no AlertDialog.setTypeFace() method available...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to create your own dialog with a custom view, say with a TextView that has the custom font in it.